# Static files with Docker when only Nginx is on host system

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I have Nginx on my host machine (Ubuntu server). How should I set up static files when using Docker?

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web: &django
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=local
    image: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/web/Dockerfile
    command: /gunicorn.sh
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8083:5000"
```

In another project (with no Docker) I have this setting in `sites-enabled/mysite`:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/myproject;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can use [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) to share the static folder from the container to host system, like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web: &django
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=local
    image: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /path/to/static/folder:/static
    command: /gunicorn.sh
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8083:5000"
```

Now, use nginx to serve those contents from that path:

```
location /static/ {    
    autoindex on;    
    alias /path/to/static/folder/; 
}
```

Here, I am assuming you are using `/static` as static root for your django project in docker.

Answer (score 1):

What I did here whas this:

- web application in a docker (like yours)
- NGINX in a container
- use docker-compose
- in docker-compose.yml from NGINX, in volumes I set the folder for static files:

  volumes:

  ```
  - /folder/myproject/static:/home/myproject/static
  ```

Possible there are many other ways to do this, but I need to delivery the jobs, so, that was the only wat I can do it.

Regards